# Path connectedness of a certain subspace of measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Note: Functions that differ on a null set are not identified.

Consider the space of measurable functions $[0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ that are continuous exactly on a set of Lebesgue measure $r$ , $0 < r < 1$ under the sup norm.

Is this space path connected?

Comment: What does "continuous exactly on a set of Lebesgue measure r" mean?  Is this set fixed?  What about its complement, is the function required to be everywhere discontinuous there?

Comment: The set {a| f is continuous at a} has measure r. The set is not fixed.

Comment: And what is the sup norm here?  The ordinary supremum of f?  The supremum of the restriction of f to its set of continuity?  The essential supremum of f?

Comment: Just the normal supremum.